# Trying to get property of non-object with syntax error

Tags: php, arrays, json, opencart

I created a instagram feed for opencart and when i wrote the code in normal php file it worked perfectly but when i transformed to opencart controller view it returns when

```
json_last_error();

int(4) syntax error
```

and here is my code in controller

```
$response= utf8_encode(file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/user/?__a=1"));
$response= str_replace(array('ï',''), '',$response);
$response= json_decode($response);
$data['orgimages'] = json_last_error();
```

i tried so many solutions or filtering out methods and that is my final code as it was changed so many times from stackoverflow answer solution for other questions but nothing seems to be worked out and even their forums didn't worked out with my issue.

Comment: Please add in your Q the json of your pull, so we can check why it is invalid

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error indicates that your json is wrongly formatted so try to echo it and validate it. I am suspecting that your json is not a valid json.

Use this : https://jsonlint.com/  validator for json.

After this line :

```
$response= str_replace(array('ï',''), '',$response);
```

`echo` your `$response` variable and see how your json looks like

Comment: But what is your response look like? Does it return a valid json in opencart?

Comment: well i tried outputing and strange! it doesn;t return json data and rather it returns instagram html cource code.

Comment: Exactly, that's what your error says actually that you have an invalid json. Which leads back to `file_get_contents`

Comment: So why does it return html  code in opencart and jason code in simple php file?

Comment: Is it the same url and the same code you are using here? Because html comes from an external url it's not on your code.

Comment: That's where the html comes from. You can use instagram official apis to retrieve data. But that's another thing to discuss you can have a look also in the official documentation.